# Find and select the item found in the combobox list

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

In the code below, I check if the value of Sheet2 cell `A1` is contained in combobox1 list and, if found, put it in the *'selection mode'*. But it does not work. Which part of the code should be corrected?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
  Me.ComboBox1.List = xRg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim foundRng As Range
  Set findrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
  Set foundRng = findrange.Find(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"))

  If foundRng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
  Else
    MsgBox "I Found"
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = foundRng.Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declare variables and provide for correct data types**

I didn't change your code too much, but would like to give you some hints:

1. Set `Option Explicit` to compel yourself to declare variables (objects).
2. Provide for input cases in your `Sheet2!A1` cell where a type mismatch could occur if you compare a string or an empty string (and not a number) against `ListIndex` numbers.
3. It's recommended to fully qualify your range references *(fqrr)*.
4. Prefer to use the term `Worksheets` if you are referring to worksheets only.
5. Check Stack Overflow's  [Help Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
   regarding [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and,
   [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
6. Try to learn something about **error handling** and **Debugging VBA** in order to be in the position to give more precise information about occurring errors. *"It doesn't work"* is like a *red rag for a bull* to more experienced programmers at this site, be more *precise* here :-;

**Some minor changes ...**

```
Option Explicit      ' declaration head of your UserForm code module
Dim xrg As Range     ' possibly declared here to be known in all UserForm procedures

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set xrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")  ' << fully qualified range reference (fqrr)
Me.ComboBox1.List = xrg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim foundRng As Range, findrange As Range
Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5") ' fqrr
Set foundRng = findrange.Find(Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")) ' fqrr
If foundRng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
ElseIf foundRng.Value = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Empty search item"
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
Else
    MsgBox "1 item found"
    If IsNumeric(foundRng.Value) Then
       Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = CLng(foundRng.Value) + 1
    Else
       Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = foundRng.Row - 1
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

**Recommended link**

You can find a helpful guide about [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) at Chip Pearson's site.

**Addendum due to comment**

In order to define a dynamic range without following empty rows you could rewrite the `Initialize` procedure as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim n&                           ' ... As Long 
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    n = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set xrg = .Range("A1:B" & n)  ' << fully qualified range reference 
End With
Me.ComboBox1.List = xrg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub
```

Good luck for future learning steps :-)

Comment: Hi dear friend T.M.! Thank you for your complete explanation. I'm glad you like me to make progress as you do. In the text of the code asked, It was only necessary to change `Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = foundRng.Value` to `Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = foundRng.Row - 1`. only this. be happy.

Comment: I changed the values of the cells to `.Range("A:B")`. But at the end of the ComboBox list, it also lists all empty rows. How can these blank values not be displayed? I tested code `.End(xlUp)` but failed.

Comment: Edited my answer due to comment - BTW there is a huge number of working coding examples covering this aspect at SO (Stack Overflow). So if you have a problem with `.End(xlUp)` it's always good use to post the *complete code part* that didn't work, otherwise one can only make presumptions. Nevertheless, I hope having helped -:) @FirstLast